# Proving $f''(c)<0$ in the given condition.

Tags: calculus

> A twice differentiable function $f(x)$ defined on $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$,. $f(c)>0$ for all $a<c<b$, prove that there exist at least one value $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f''(c)<0$.

I tried by  starting with Rolle's theorem and got there exist a point '$s$'  between $a$ and $b$ as $f'(s)=0$. I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Can you turn this into a question?  I don't understand what you are trying to prove.

Comment: I don't understand $f(c)>0$ for all $a$.

Comment: @felipeh A twice differentiable function f(x) defined on [a,b] such that f(a)=f(b)=0,. f(c)>0 for all a<c<b, prove that there exist at least one value c in (a,b) such that f"(c)<0.

Comment: I don't know why is it not displaying full question.

Comment: @Gribouillis A twice differentiable function f(x) defined on [a,b] such that f(a)=f(b)=0,. f(c)>0 for all a<c<b, prove that there exist at least one value c in (a,b) such that f"(c)<0.

Comment: Thanks @palashjain, that's a helpful comment.  See if you can edit your post to explain your question in complete sentences.  It's also useful to keep the partial work you did with Roll's theorem so that people know where to help you out and understand that you have already tried working on the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, @palashjain, are you sure the question you're asking is correct?  My first comments were on the presentation, but I still don't understand why you expect what you're asking to prove is correct.

Comment: @felipeh  i am asking to prove that f"(c)<0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(a)=0$ and $f(c)>0$, we can conclude that the right derivative $f'(a) \ge 0$.

Since $f(b)=0$ and $f(c)>0$, we can conclude that the left derivative $f'(b) \le 0$.

Suppose $f''(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then $f'(a) \le f'(x) \le f'(b)$, which implies $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, which implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, a contradiction.

Another proof:

Choose a $c \in (a,b)$. We know that $f(c)>0$.

Then there exists $p\in (a,c)$ so that $f'(p)>0$, and $q \in (c,b)$ so that $f'(q)<0$.

Then there exists $r \in (p,q)$ so that $f''(r) < 0$

Comment: Why is it true $f''(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then $f'(a)<f'(x)<f'(b)$?

Comment: User170039: use integration.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be any fixed point in $(a, b)$. Then by Mean Value Theorem we can see that that there is a $d\in(a, c)$ such that $f'(d) =(f(c) - f(a)) /(c-a) >0$ and there is an $e\in(c, b) $ such that $f'(e) =(f(b) - f(c)) /(b-c) <0$. And thus by Mean Value Theorem we have $\xi\in (d, e) $ such that $f''(\xi) =(f'(e) - f'(d))/(e-d) <0$.

---

Note that we need to have just one single point $c\in(a, b) $ such that $f(c)>0$ for the above argument to work. The question has unnecessarily give that $f$ is positive on whole interval $(a, b) $.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

1. By the extreme value theorem, let $c$ be such that $f(c)$ is maximal (actually any $c$ between $a$ and $b$ will do by the given conditions).  Observe that $f(c)>0$.
2. By the mean value theorem, there is some $x$ such that $a<x<c$ and $f'(x)>0$.  Similarly, there is some $y$ such that $c<y<b$ and $f'(y)<0$.
3. By the mean value theorem, there is some $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f''(z)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$.  Observe that the numerator is negative and the denominator is positive.  Therefore, $f''(z)<0$.